# How to create a table object prototype using arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype-programming

Suppose this constitute a table:

```
rows:
            [
                //TABLE 1
                { //TABLE 1 TITLE HEADER
                    cells: [
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: "Table 1", textAlign: "center", bold: "true"}
                    ]
                },
                { // Header A
                    cells: [
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: "Month", textAlign: "center", verticalAlign: "center", background: "rgb(198,217,241)", bold: "true"},
                    {value: "Metric", textAlign: "center", bold: "true"},
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: "Achievement (%)", textAlign: "center", verticalAlign: "center", bold: "true"},
                    {value: "Weight  (%)", textAlign: "center", bold: "true"},
                    ]
                },
                { // Header B
                    cells: [
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: "Plan", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(192,0,0)", bold: "true", color:"white"},
                    {value: "Actual", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(0,176,80)", bold: "true", color:"white"},
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: "50", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(198,217,241)"}]
                },
                { // Table1 row1
                    cells: [
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: "1", textAlign: "center"},
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(242,220,219)"},
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(235,241,222)"},
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(198,217,241)", bold:"true"},
                    { value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(198,217,241)", bold:"true"}]
                },
                { // Table1 row2
                    cells: [
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: "2", textAlign: "center"},
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(242,220,219)" },
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(235,241,222)"},
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(198,217,241)", bold:"true"},
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(198,217,241)", bold:"true"}]
                }
                { // FOOTER
                    cells: [
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: "Average per month", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(198,217,241)", bold:"true"},
                    {value: ""},
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(198,217,241)", bold:"true"},
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(198,217,241)", bold:"true"},
                    {value: "", textAlign: "center", background: "rgb(255,192,0)", bold:"true"}]
                }
            ]
```

How do I make object prototypes for the table and the rows so I can iterate multiple table instances with multiple rows, given that a table consist of

- 1 title header
- 1 header A and 1 header B
- at least 1 row, but can be iterated indefinitely
- 1 footer

What I want to do is to make a constructor/prototype function for the "table" and rows objects so that I can loop the "rows" with increasing index number without needing to manually re-write/add the rows/tables with the same schema.

**Update**: to add more context, [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ocLotka/5/) shows the "tables" and "rows" I want to iterate.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: What is the question??

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! Basically I want to make a constructor/prototype for the "table" so i can store the "row" objects as well as loop the rows without needing to manually rewrite/add a row with the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this class-like implementation?:

```js
var Tabel = (function () {
    function Tabel(params) {
        if (params === void 0) { params = {}; }
        this.table = (params.table == void 0 ? document.createElement("table") : params.table);
        if (params.attributes != void 0) {
            for (var key in params.attributes) {
                if (params.attributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var attribute = params.attributes[key];
                    this.table.setAttribute(key, attribute);
                }
            }
        }
        this.thead = this.table.appendChild(document.createElement("thead"));
        this.tbody = this.table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));
        this.tfoot = this.table.appendChild(document.createElement("tfoot"));
        this.rows = (params.rows == void 0 ? [] : params.rows)
            .sort(function (a, b) {
            var A = (a.headOrFoot == void 0 ? 0 : (a.headOrFoot ? 1 : -1));
            var B = (b.headOrFoot == void 0 ? 0 : (b.headOrFoot ? 1 : -1));
            return B - A;
        });
        this.render();
    }
    Tabel.prototype.render = function () {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.renderHandle);
        this.renderHandle = requestAnimationFrame(this._render.bind(this));
    };
    Tabel.prototype._render = function () {
        this.thead.innerHTML = this.tbody.innerHTML = this.tfoot.innerHTML = "";
        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < this.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
            var row = this.rows[rowIndex];
            var inHead = (row.headOrFoot == void 0 ? 0 : (row.headOrFoot ? 1 : -1));
            var tr = void 0;
            if (inHead == 1) {
                tr = this.thead.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
            }
            else if (inHead == 0) {
                tr = this.tbody.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
            }
            else {
                tr = this.tfoot.appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
            }
            for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.cells.length; cellIndex++) {
                var cell = row.cells[cellIndex];
                var td = tr.appendChild(document.createElement(inHead != 0 ? 'th' : 'td'));
                if (cell.attributes != void 0) {
                    for (var key in cell.attributes) {
                        if (cell.attributes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            var attribute = cell.attributes[key];
                            td.setAttribute(key, attribute);
                        }
                    }
                }
                td.innerHTML = cell.data.toString();
            }
        }
    };
    return Tabel;
}());
//Test
var t1 = new Tabel({
    attributes: {
        id: "table-1",
        "class": "table table-striped"
    },
    rows: [
        {
            cells: [
                { data: "ID", attributes: { style: "text-align: center", colspan: 1 } },
                { data: "Name" },
                { data: "Month" },
                { data: "Header" }
            ],
            headOrFoot: true
        }, {
            cells: [
                { data: "ID", attributes: { style: "text-align: center", colspan: 1 } },
                { data: "Name" },
                { data: "Month" },
                { data: "Footer" }
            ],
            headOrFoot: false
        }, {
            cells: [
                { data: 1 },
                { data: "Bob" },
                { data: "January", attributes: { colspan: 2 } }
            ]
        }, {
            cells: [
                { data: 2 },
                { data: "Bill" },
                { data: "March", attributes: { colspan: 2 } }
            ]
        }, {
            cells: [
                { data: 3 },
                { data: "Mona" },
                { data: "March", attributes: { colspan: 2 } }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
document.body.appendChild(t1.table);
```